# Remove a media type from a controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a controller with a number of getter methods that produce `application/vnd.api+json`and `application/json`. I have one patch method that supports `application/json-patch+json`.

To avoid repetitive attributes on the getter method, I have a `[Produces]` at the class level

```
[Produces("application/json", "application/vnd.api+json")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{ ... }
```

This is fine, but when looking at the Swagger UI documentation page that gets generated, the patch says it's supporting all 3 media types above, which is wrong.

So, I want a way to remove the two that get applied to the patch method. I tried to create, effectively, the opposite of `[Produces]`.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class DoesNotProduceAttribute : Attribute, IApiDefaultResponseMetadataProvider, IOrderedFilter
{
    public DoesNotProduceAttribute(string contentTypeToRemove, params string[] otherContentTypesToRemove)
    {
        ContentTypes.Add(contentTypeToRemove);
        otherContentTypesToRemove.ForEach(ContentTypes.Add);
    }

    public void SetContentTypes(MediaTypeCollection contentTypes)
    {
        foreach (var contentType in ContentTypes)
            contentTypes.Remove(contentType);
    }

    public MediaTypeCollection ContentTypes { get; } = new MediaTypeCollection();
    ...
}
```

and apply that to my method

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
[DoesNotProduce("application/json", "application/vnd.api+json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string id, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<Value> patchDocument)
{ ... }
```

However the `SetContentTypes()` method is not called. What am I missing? Is there another way of removing the content types I don't want for the patch method?

Comment: Doesn't a `Produces` attribute on the method override the attribute on the class?

Comment: Based on the code, it's more "in addition to" not an override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a *ResultFilterAttribute* and override the OnResultExecuted method which is triggered right after the action gets executed. This way you're removing the content types from the ObjectResult returned back to the consumer of the api.

**Filter:**

```cs
public class RemoveContentTypeAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute {
    public MediaTypeCollection ContentTypes { get; } = new MediaTypeCollection();

    public RemoveContentTypeAttribute(string contentType, params string[] otherContentTypes) {
        ContentTypes.Add(contentType);
        foreach (var currentContentType in otherContentTypes) {
            ContentTypes.Add(currentContentType);
        }
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context) {
        var result = (ObjectResult)context.Result;
        foreach (var contentType in ContentTypes) {
            result.ContentTypes.Remove(contentType);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```cs
[RemoveContentType("application/json", "application/vnd.api+json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string id, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<Value> patchDocument)
{ ... }
```